# Adding another sort option to dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have these lines of code which adds item to a dropdown list and sorts them by hearing date and then by time. I would like to take it a step further and sort by the 'type' or description  of the item in alphabetical order.

this is my code in my Controller:

```
public void AddHearingsToViewModel(CourtActivityViewModel viewModel, IQueryable<Hearing> hearings)
    {
        if (viewModel.HearingEntryId == Guid.Empty)
            viewModel.HearingEntryId = hearings.OrderByDescending(h => h.HearingDate).ThenByDescending(d=>d.HearingDate).FirstOrDefault().HearingEntryId;
        viewModel.Hearings = hearings.ToSelectList("HearingEntryId", "CourtActivitySelection", viewModel.HearingEntryId.ToString());
    }
```

My ..Domain.Entities.Hearing

```
public partial class Hearing
{

    public string CourtActivitySelection
    {
        get { return string.Format(@"{0:d} - {0:t} - {1} ", HearingDate, HearingType.Description); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(@"{1} on {0:d} @ {0:t}", HearingDate, HearingType.Description);
    }
}

public partial class HearingEntry
{

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(@"{1} on {0:d} @ {0:t}", HearingDate, HearingType.Description);
    }

}
```

I tried:

```
viewModel.HearingEntryId = hearings.OrderByDescending(h => h.HearingDate).ThenByDescending(d=>d.HearingDate).OrderBy(t=>t.HearingType).FirstOrDefault().HearingEntryId;
```

The exact error is :

Cannot order by type 'Kids.Domain.Entities.HearingType'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot order by type 'Kids.Domain.Entities.HearingType'.

And the line in red is the line i added the `.ThenBy(t=>t.HearingType)`

Comment: Your `.OrderBy(t=>t.HearingType)` should probably be `.ThenBy(t=>t.HearingType)`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips just tried it and i still get the same error. I am not sure what that error really means like what would be the reason for that.

Comment: It would be best if you could copy and paste the *exact* error message, as we have no context for what your model looks like, nor what each property type is.

Comment: Did you implement IComparable in your objects?

Comment: @ErikPhilips added more code and error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `HearingType` is a class that does not implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx).  Either implement this interface on the Type that HearingType is

```
public SomeClassThatHearingTypeIsAnInstanceOf : IComparable
{
}
```

or change your code to

```
.ThenBy(t=>t.HearingType.SomePropertyYouWantToSortBy)
```

The only problem you may run into (since I don't know how your classes are populated, is that `HearingType` could be `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked for me! and about the hearing type could be null i already check for that so i will be good to go. Thanks again.